# How to get logged in Active Directory username in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-directory, single-sign-on, ruby-on-rails-6

How can I fetch the logged in AD user in my ROR application.

I have tried:

```
Etc.getlogin - It gives me the username of where the server is running
system(`WhoAmI`) - returns false
ENV["USERNAME"], ENV["USER"], ENV["USERID"] - Doesn't return anything
```

And how to check if the User is logged in or not ?

```
I am using Net::LDAP for this:

a = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq("sAMAccountName", "username")
ldap.search(:filter => a)

It return me the data of the user as :

@myhash=
{:dn=>["CN=Test Windows,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=local"],
:objectclass=>["top", "person", "organizationalPerson", "user"],
:cn=>["Test Windows"],
:sn=>["Windows"],
:givenname=>["Test"],
:distinguishedname=>["CN=Test Windows,CN=Users,DC=example,DC=local"],
:instancetype=>["4"],
:whencreated=>["20211004113850.0Z"],
:whenchanged=>["20211004124559.0Z"],
:displayname=>["Test Windows"],
:usncreated=>["16489"],
:usnchanged=>["16525"],
:name=>["Test Windows"],
:objectguid=>["Some ID"],
:useraccountcontrol=>["22038"],
:badpwdcount=>["0"],
:codepage=>["0"],
:countrycode=>["0"],
:badpasswordtime=>["0"],
:lastlogoff=>["0"],
:lastlogon=>["0"],
:pwdlastset=>["1327782117765465"],
:primarygroupid=>["213"],
:objectsid=>["Some ID"],
:accountexpires=>["9223876536854775807"],
:logoncount=>["0"],
:samaccountname=>["username"],
:samaccounttype=>["93806368"],
:userprincipalname=>["username@example.local"],
:objectcategory=>["CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=example,DC=local"],
:dscorepropagationdata=>["16010101000000.0Z"],
:mail=>["abc@abc.com"]}>]
```

But here how to know if the user is logged in ?

lastlogoff & lastlogon is always "0"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MSAL API should let us know the username that is currently logged in so that we don't have to create a separate cookie and manage this cookie and logic.

getAllAcounts should give us all the accounts.
getAccount should give us the account that it is currently signed in/active.

Here is how you can check if user is loggedIn or not:

```
cdef raw_info
    @raw_info ||= access_token.get('/me').parse
```

Then you can check if the token is valid or not. If it is valid then the user is loggedIn otherwise not.